# Absolute position for Background

Tags: html, css, background

is it possible to give a background in html via CSS an absolute position?
*background-attachment: fixed;* doesn't work because that prevents scrolling:

Or a diffrent way to achieve what I want:
Is it possible to attach multiple elements to a single background at a common position?
The thing is, I want to achieve a see-through effect by displaying parts of the global background of my page behind each element. Those elements can move via animations though, so I need some independent position where to draw the background.

Big thanks in advance! ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `background-position` property?

For example:

```
background-position: 0% 0%;
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. It seems to be relative to the local element, even when using percentage values.

Comment: I can help you better if you give me a fiddle or something to work with :-)